# Why is my UISearchTableView reference getting lost after search when didSelectRowAtIndex is called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

My search is working perfectly fine and normally when filtering but after I select a cell the indexPath of the didSelectRowAtIndex indexPath parameter is always null and the tableView that is passed into that method is always UITableView instead of a UISearchTableView, meaning the commonly used if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) statement always returns false even though if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) will correctly return true. Thanks you for any help or advice.

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if ([self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Beer"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Wine"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Liquor"] ){
    id  sectionInfo =
    [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}else{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){

        return [_searchResults count];
    }else{
        return [_drinks count];
    }
} }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"drink";
SWTableViewCell *cell = (SWTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
Drink *drinkCell;

    if ([self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Beer"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Wine"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Liquor"] ){
    drinkCell = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }else{
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
            drinkCell = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }else{
        drinkCell = [_drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

}
   //Check if cell object has already been favorited, if it has render unfavorite button instead
    NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSString *favoriteText;
    if ([drinkCell.isFavorite boolValue]){
        favoriteText = @"Unfavorite";
    }else{
        favoriteText = @"Favorite";
    }
        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0]
                                                    title:favoriteText];


    //Can only delete a drink if it is custom
    if ([drinkCell.isCustom boolValue] && drinkCell.isCustom != nil){
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
     [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f]
                                                title:@"Delete"];

        [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:0.231f green:0.231f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f]
                                                    title:@"Edit"];

    }

    cell = [[SWTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                              containingTableView:self.tableView // For row height and selection
                               leftUtilityButtons:nil
                              rightUtilityButtons:rightUtilityButtons];
    cell.delegate = self;


// Configure the cell...

[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath tableView:tableView];

return cell;}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath tableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
Drink *drinkCell;
if ([self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Beer"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Wine"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Liquor"] ){
    drinkCell = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}else{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){

        drinkCell = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else{
         drinkCell = [_drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


}
cell.textLabel.text = drinkCell.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", drinkCell.alcoholByVolume];
```

}

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate;

if ([self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Beer"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Wine"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Liquor"]){
    resultPredicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@ AND drinkType ==%@",searchText, self.currentDrinkType];
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Root%@", self.currentDrinkType]];
    [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:resultPredicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

}else{
            resultPredicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@",searchText];
    _searchResults = [[_drinks filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]mutableCopy];

}
```

}

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{ 
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;}




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
 Drink *theDrink;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
NSLog(@"search index %@", [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]);
}
selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
NSLog(@"selected index path %d", selectedIndexPath.row);
NSManagedObject *selectedDrink;
if ([self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Beer"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Wine"] || [self.currentDrinkType.name isEqualToString:@"Liquor"] ){
            theDrink = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedDrink = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

}else{
    if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive){
        selectedDrink = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        theDrink = [_searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else{
       selectedDrink = [_drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        theDrink = [_drinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

}


[selectedDrink setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastChosen"];
NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);

}

self.selectedDrink = theDrink;
[self.delegateDrink drinkTableViewControllerDidFinish:self];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The delegate methods which begin with a UITableView instance parameter need to distinguish between the regular table view and the one for search results. The index path parameter matches the table view (i.e., regular or search). Check that you are getting the index path appropriate for the table view you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I am calling the "if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
NSLog(@"search index %@", [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]);
}" this method never gets called even when it is being called while in the search results. So I am checking which table view I am in, the problem is that the tableView that is passed in is not a searchResultsTableView like it should be.